# Python - Acquiring a count of file extensions across all directories

Tags: python

we have a hardrive with hundreds of thousands of files

i need to figure out how many of every file extension we have

how can i do this with python?

i need it to go through every directory. this lawyers at my company need this. it can be a total for the entire hardrive it does not have to be broken down by directory

example:

```
1232 JPEG
11 exe
45 bat
2342 avi
532 doc
```

Comment: Have you checked out os.walk?

Comment: Ah, lawyers! Do they really care about file *extensions* rather than content or type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at `os.walk` call in the os module and traverse through the entire directory tree. Get the extension using `os.path.splitext`. Maintain a dictionary where key the extension.lower() and increment the count of each extension that you encounter.

```
import os
import collections
extensions = collections.defaultdict(int)

for path, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
   for filename in files:
       extensions[os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower()] += 1

for key,value in extensions.items():
    print 'Extension: ', key, ' ', value, ' items'
```

Comment: And `os.path.splitext` handles some special cases, e.g. filenames that begin with a dot.

Comment: @Reiner, yes splitext is good idea. Modified and used it in the same snippet.

Comment: `splitext` returns a tuple (root, ext). You probably want to use the second element only (right now it uses the whole tuple as key to the dictionary). Besides, is it necessary to retrieve the absolute path of the file? In my opinion only the filename itself is of interest here.

Comment: @Reiner,I overlooked that splitext part (did not refer to the documentation), Sorry for that, I corrected it and I had immediately modified the absolute path thing in my code, as it was not required. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: This is the _exact_ solution I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
from os.path import splitext

extensions = {}
for root, dir, files in os.walk('/'):
    for file in files:
        ext = splitext(file)[1]
        try:
            extensions[ext] += 1
        except KeyError:
            extensions[ext] = 1
```

You'd probably be better served by using a `DefaultDict`, you can use that if you like.

You can then print the values like so:

```
for extension, count in extensions.items():
    print 'Extension %s has %d files' % (extension, count)
```

Comment: @JOE no it doesn't. That would be simple to fix though (note it will take a really long time to run if you point it at root)

Comment: @JOE I added a loop to output the data

Comment: JOE, Rafe has the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `os.walk()` to go through the files, and `os.path.splitext()` to get just the extensions. You may want to `lower()` the extensions too, because at least in my $HOME I have a bunch of .jpg and a bunch of .JPG.

```
import os, os.path, collections
extensionCount = collections.defaultdict(int)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        extensionCount[ext.lower()] += 1
#Now print them out, largest to smallest.
for ext, count in sorted(extensionCount.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print ext, count
```

Comment: NameError: name 'defaultdict' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, fixed. It should have been `collections.defaultdict` instead of just `defaultdict`. Also have a better print statement now.

Comment: For python 2.7 and up: see also [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which is even easier than `defaultdict`

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is simple.

```
counter = 0 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(YourPath):
    for file in files:    
        if file.endswith(EXTENSION):
            counter += 1
```

You can create an array with the list of EXTENSION and add them. Another faster way would be to create a dictionary growing little by little. The extension is then a key for adding values. {jpeg: 1232, exe: 11}

Update: With many of the solutions we propose is that we assume that the string is a correct representation of the filetype. But I'm not sure there is any other way of doing it.  The iteration should be done **only once** indeed as the comment says below. So it is better to grow the dictionary little by little

Comment: Any reason why the for loop is indented? Also, this would be a less efficient way to do it (dictionary lookup is way cheap, iteration is not)

Comment: the indentation is due to clumsiness I will fix it

Answer (score 0):

The working script will be very simple and I recommend you use os.walk() function. What it does is generates file names across directory tree( http://docs.python.org/library/os.html).