# Get the sum by file extensions in python

Tags: python

Newbie question here!

I'm trying to get the sum of file sizes by file extension in a directory. So far I'm using a modified version of this (via [Python - Acquiring a count of file extensions across all directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903878/python-acquiring-a-count-of-file-extensions-across-all-directories)) to count them.

Trying to use os.path.getsize() then use sum() to add them up, but I either get zero or errors.

What am I missing?

The code I copied is this:

```
import os
import collections
extensions = collections.defaultdict(int)

place = input('Type the directory path: ')

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(place):
   for filename in files:
       extensions[os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower()] += 1

for key,value in extensions.items():
    print ('Extension: ', key, ' ', value, ' items')
```

Comment: Show us some code, please.

Comment: Edited! I tried to write in something like this: os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower() but it wouldn't work, I see I was missing some stuff as other users have shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
import os
import collections
extensions = collections.defaultdict(int)
size = collections.defaultdict(int)

for path, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
   for filename in files:
       extensions[os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower()] += 1
       size[os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower()] += os.path.getsize(path+os.sep+filename)

for key,value in extensions.items():
    print 'Extension: ', key, ' ', value, ' items'

for key,value in size.items():
    print 'Extension: ', key, ' ', value, ' size'
```

this is based on your link

Comment: Ahh, I see. So what is the .sep+filename part? I would have never thought of that!

Comment: Thank you, this answer is closest to the code I was trying to write, I still encounter the same error as the answer given by Xu Ding.

Answer (score 1):

Just replaced one line in the reference code:

```
import os
import collections
extensions = collections.defaultdict(int)

for path, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
   for filename in files:
       # add file size to the extension dictionary item, instead of add 1 
       extensions[os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower()] += os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path,filename))

for key,value in extensions.items():
    print 'Extension: %s, Size: %s' % (key, value)
```

Comment: This worked on a smaller folder, but when I tried it C:/Users/Me it gave me a FileNotFoundError for a file that looks something like this: services.apps.microsoft.com/browse.6.2....dat - I'll write an exception handling to ignore things like this, but why it worked before and not after adding your code is perplexing me.

Comment: Could you give the full path of the file? It seems to be a corner case.

Comment: File "C:\Python33\lib\genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:/Users/Joh\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\WinStore_cw5n1h2txyewy\\AC\\Microsoft\\Windows Store\\Cache\\0\\0-Namespace-https∺∯∯services.apps.microsoft.com∯browse∯6.2.9200-1∯615∯en-US∯c∯US∯Namespace∯pc∯00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000∯00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.dat'